# Does NSFileHandle -readDataOfLength: return autoreleased NSData?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata, nsfilehandle

When I call `readDataOfLength:` on an `NSFileHandle` instance, do I need to release the returned `NSData`? Currently I'm not, but I would like to get rid of this nagging doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Cocoa's [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) say that you only own (and thus need to release) objects returned from a method whose name contains one of "*new*", "*alloc*", "*retain*", or "*copy*" (**NARC**). Since that method contains none of those, you know you don't need to release it.

Comment: Thanks. **NARC** is a great mnemonic. Now I can sleep at night.

Comment: Or, with NARColepsy, you can sleep during the day.

Comment: NARColeptics can be mistaken for NSZombies.  I think there was a Poe short story about that...

Answer (score 1):

The standard that is observed very consistently within Objective C libraries is that a method beginning with "alloc" or "copy" (and, I'm thinking, some other obscure verb) returns a retained object, while everything else returns an autoreleased object.

Any exceptions should be well-documented in the specs.

Comment: The obscure word is “new”, which hardly anybody uses (this may change as people adopt ARC…), and the other one, not obscure at all, is `retain`. Note that just because a method doesn't return an owning reference doesn't mean it returns an autoreleased object.

Comment: If a method does not return an autoreleased object (and is not one of the noted exceptions) then it *must* be documented.  (This goes for user-written methods as well as the Objective C library.)

Comment: As stated, untrue. What I think you meant to say is that “If a method *returns an owning reference* (and does not follow the naming patterns), then it *must* be documented”. That is true. A method can return an object without returning an ownership or autoreleasing the object.